# How to get multiple images and video from gallery

Tags: android, image, video

Now i am going on with the selection of multiple **images and video** from the gallery went through the below

https://github.com/luminousman/MultipleImagePick

Here i am only able to get the image but not the video and also i am only able pick can't able to set the type of whether it is image video as like do in default android intent method      **intent.setType("image/* video/*");**

Is there any other way to get both images and video to gether and differntate it.

If anyone have idea about this please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: u cannot get the video from sdcard u can get viedo thounmail in imageview just u think how to get viedo from sdcard

Comment: MultipleImagePick only for image not for viedo

Comment: http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/05/display-video-thumbnail-in-listview.html

Comment: can u refer any tutorial to pick multiple images from gallery

Comment: no isuue from this i also use it many project https://github.com/luminousman/MultipleImagePick

Comment: is any other way to pick video along with selection of multiple images